# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.13.12 on localhost while creating a new policy in ditto

Tags: docker, nginx, bad-gateway, eclipse-ditto

I am new to docker, I'm using docker on windows 10 and am using Eclipse Ditto and Eclipse Mosquitto, I have to create a twin device. Before that I have to create a new policy via Postman, 
While executing the policy am getting the following error:

[image]

The code to create the new policy is ass follow

```
curl -X put 'http://localhost:8080/api/2/policies/my.test:policy' -u 'ditto:ditto' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "entries": {
        "owner": {
            "subjects": {
                "nginx:ditto": {
                    "type": "nginx basic auth user"
                }
            },
            "resources": {
                "thing:/": {
                    "grant": [
                        "READ","WRITE"
                    ],
                    "revoke": []
                },
                "policy:/": {
                    "grant": [
                        "READ","WRITE"
                    ],
                    "revoke": []
                },
                "message:/": {
                    "grant": [
                        "READ","WRITE"
                    ],
                    "revoke": []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I'm following the procedure given in [this](https://github.com/eclipse/ditto-examples/tree/master/mqtt-bidirectional) link

is there any solution to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the Eclipse Ditto `gateway` service was not running correctly.
I'm confident that you figured out to look at the output of `docker-compose ps` and restarted the services.

Comment: I followed your explainations and made sure that the services are up but still get 502 Bad Gateway - Also for "Create Thing" - Any idea whad need to be configured in the Nginx ?